Improving the correct Constant in Lemma 3 of "Explicit Estimates for the Riemann Zeta Function" by Cheng and Graham
I am studying quadratic exponential sums of the form $f(x) $ = $\alpha x^2$ + $ \beta x $ + $ \gamma $ and attempting to improve the constant in Lemma 3 of the paper:

Explicit estimates for the Riemann zeta function, Rocky Mt. J. Math. 34, No. 4, 1261-1280 (2004), MR2095256, Zbl 1062.11056, by Yuanyou F. Cheng and Sidney W. Graham   (JSTOR link) .

I have explored the following references to better understand techniques related to exponential sums:

Explicit Sub-Weyl Bound for the Riemann Zeta Function by Dhir Patel (Thesis)
Exponential sums and their applications. Transl. from the Russian by Yu. N. Shakhov, Mathematics and Its Applications. Soviet Series. 80. Dordrecht etc.: Kluwer Academic Publishers. xv, 209 p. (1992), MR1162539, Zbl 0754.11022, by N.M. Korobov
"Explicit bounds on $\boldsymbol\zeta (s)$ in the critical strip and a zero-free region", J. Math. Anal. Appl. 534, No. 2, Article ID 128124, 53 p. (2024), MR4693232, Zbl 1543.11077, by Andrew Yang
"On Kuzmin–Landau Lemma" by J. Arias de Reyna
The Hardy-Littlewood method., Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics. 125. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. vii, 232 p. (1997), MR1435742, Zbl 0868.11046, by R.C. Vaughan
Analytic number theory, Colloquium Publications. American Mathematical Society 53. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3633-1/hbk). xi, 615 p. (2004), MR2061214, Zbl 1059.11001, by Iwaniec and Kowalski.

Despite my efforts, I am struggling to fully understand the advanced techniques and apply them to the problem.
My Questions:

Are there additional sources or references that you think might help me improve my understanding and refine the bounds for quadratic exponential sums?
How can I ensure that I fully understand what I am reading in these advanced papers and books?

Should I focus on specific prerequisites or foundational texts before diving deeper into these references?



I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for new resources or strategies for approaching this problem effectively. Thank you!
